# What is the use of "This is a Great Comment"?

Tags: support, comment-voting

I wish to know the use of  "This is a Great Comment".

How does it help the person who has posted the comment and also to the person who has posted the question?

Comment: Questions _about_ SO, should be asked on meta.stackoverflow.com

Comment: @Oded that is a great comment

Comment: I think that `[stackoverflow.com]` tag should be made a synonym of `[stackoverflow]`, so at least the question will get a correct tag when migrated here.

Answer (score 3):

You mean the comment vote function?

Well, for one, it allows others to agree with a point of view, without having to write it down themselves. That is good because

- It avoids cluttering
- Other people may not be able to put it as well as the comment author did

secondly, it is a great way of giving feedback what people think is an especially great, or witty comment.

Comment: Especially when some comments may add as much information, or even correct, an unedited answer.